# Correctly pointing a GameObects rotation to the mouse position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
Quaternion FromToRote = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.right, new Vector3(roadEnd.x, roadEnd.y, roadEnd.z) - road.position);
road.transform.rotation = FromToRote;
```

I have this piece of code handling my rotation. It rotates a GameObject to the position of my mouse, but the x axis rotates to -90 when moving towards the right.

https://gyazo.com/91fa0caee3f62b353b33e6a175e93e55

I tried to fix the x axis to 0, but that caused all the axes to default to 0. I'm not at all good with quaternions so I have no clue how to approach this.

Comment: Could you please briefly explain to where exactly you want your object to point to? The mouse cursor is in a 2d coordinate system (the screen) and the object in 3d (the world). E.g. do you cast the mouse position forward from the camera by a given amount of meters? Are you using `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint()` as described [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)? Unity's doc provide [an example here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html) of how to rotate an object towards a given other over an amount of steps.

Comment: I updated my post, hopefully it'll be more clear now.

Comment: Gotcha! Try [this answer](http://answers.unity.com/answers/651344/view.html), does it solve it?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but this did not work either. It only affected the X and Z axes and did not follow. The problem with the Quaternion.FromToRotation approach was that it would reset to whatever what was assigned for "from" when you grew near it. I want to create a rotation similar to Simcity or Cities:Skylines roads. Sorry for all the confusion, but I have no idea where to go from here. What worked most similarly was https://answers.unity.com/questions/1373642/using-quaternions-in-2d-to-follow-a-rotation-both.html but the rotation seemed to be at a 90 degree offset.